# Modifying a variable passed by reference vs returning it from a function

Tags: c

Following the advice from a [C FAQ on instantiating a matrix using a double pointer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html), I stumbled on another problem. I managed to resolve the issue, but have difficulty understanding why it works one way but not another.

I have the following code which works, and then I will show you the bit that doesn't work, and I hope you can explain why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int HEIGHT = 20;
int WIDTH = 20;

int ** curr_grid;

/**
 * Generate an array with the given height and length
 */
int ** create_grid() {
    int ** grid;
    grid = malloc(sizeof(int *) * HEIGHT);
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) 
        grid[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * WIDTH);
    return grid;
}

/* Entry Point main */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    curr_grid = create_grid();
    curr_grid[0][0] = 0;
    free(curr_grid); // Release heap resources
    return 0;
}
```

Allocating the memory for the grid and returning the pointer this way works. However, I first tried another way, which I was convinced should also work, but it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int HEIGHT = 20;
int WIDTH = 20;

int ** curr_grid;

/**
 * Generate an array with the given height and length
 */
 create_grid(int ** grid) {
    grid = malloc(sizeof(int *) * HEIGHT);
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) 
        grid[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * WIDTH);
}

/* Entry Point main */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    create_grid(curr_grid);
    curr_grid[0][0] = 0; // Segmentation Fault
    free(curr_grid); // Release heap resources
    return 0;
}
```

Doing it this way terminates with a segmentation fault on the line indicated. However, I was under the impression that passing a variable by reference allows you to modify it.

Why didn't this work?

Comment: `grid` inside the function is a **copy** of the parameter that's passed in from `main`...

Comment: your title says "passed by reference", but you don't actually do it.

Comment: It probably gives away that I am a complete C newbie. If you have any ideas for renaming the question, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath But if I pass a pointer, is that not a reference? I thought I understood, but clearly not :-(

Comment: pointers are nothing special, they act like any other type. you pass by value.

Answer (score 2):

Your not passing the address of the pointer by saying `create_grid(curr_grid);`
here its passing the value present in the curr_grid pointer ( random value ) and your taking that value into grid. which is taken of the stack as soon as the function execution is completed.

Try passing the address of your pointer which will then work fine.

`create_grid(&curr_grid);`

EDIT: Check the following link hope it might help you with graphical representation

[Pointer tutorial](http://www.augustcouncil.com/%7Etgibson/tutorial/ptr.html)

Comment: I wish there were some graphical explanation of what is going on in memory when this happens to explain what is wrong with my understanding of pointers. Thanks, for now I must take your word for it until it has penetrated my thick skull :-)

Comment: I am not sure whether to accept your answer or Michael's. He demonstrated the code better with *** in the function, but you provided a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
void create_grid(int ***grid) {
    *grid = malloc(sizeof(int *) * HEIGHT);
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) 
        (*grid)[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * WIDTH);
}

/* Entry Point main */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    create_grid(&curr_grid);
    curr_grid[0][0] = 0;
    free(curr_grid); // Release heap resources
    return 0;
}
```

It's like the example below:

```
int MyFunction()
{
  return 3 ;  // we return directly 3
}

void main()
{
  int a ;
  a = MyFunction() ;    
}
```

vs:

```
void MyFunction1(int *pa)
{
  *pa = 3 ;   // we assign 3 to the memory location pointed by pa
}

void main2()
{
  int a ;
  MyFunction1(&a) ;  // we pass the pointer to a /
  // now a contains 3
}
```

Comment: So you are saying I must pass a pointer to a pointer? I thought by virtue of the fact that it is a pointer, it is already able to modify that space in memory.

Comment: Yes. If you want to modify an int via a void function (like above) you must pass a pointer to `int`. If you want to modify a pointer to int you must pass a pointer to a pointer to `int` and so on. In your case you want to modify a pointer to a pointer to int (`int ** currgrid`) and therefore you must pass a pointer to a pointer to a pointer. And please accept my answer if it is want you were looking for.

Comment: I am not sure whether to accept your answer or const. He provided a better explanation, but does not fully demonstrate it in code with the *** like you do.

Answer (score 0):

The way to know how to pass any kind of variable (pointer or not, the rules stays the same) is this:

```
void create_grid(int **grid) {
    grid = malloc(...);
    ...
}
```

Here you are passing a variable named `grid` and you want to change it's value `grid = malloc(...);`, but as you are using only `grid` without any *, you have only a copy of grid
 and any changes done to `grids` value won't be visible outside of function.

Now in this case:

```
void create_grid(int ***grid) {
    *grid = malloc(...);
    ...
}
```

Now as you are accessing value of grid with using and '*', you know, that any changes done this way will remain after function returns, as grid is really a reference to your two dimensional array.

This is simple as that (no matter what type the variable is).